# Iterating over a data frame and replacing value depending on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to python (coming from R) and I cannot figure out how to iterate over a data frame in python. I have provided a data frame below and a list of possible "Interventions". What I am attempting to do is search through the "Intervention" column in the data frame and if the intervention is in the "intervention_list" replace the value to "Yes Intervention" but if "NaN" replace with "No Intervention".

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
intervention_list = ['Intervention 1', 'Intervention 2']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700],
                  'Intervention':['Intervention 1', 'NaN','NaN','NaN','Intervention 2','Intervention 1','NaN']})
print(df)
```

I am hoping the finished data frame would look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700],
                  'Intervention':['Yes Intervention', 'No Intervention','No Intervention','No Intervention','Yes Intervention','Yes Intervention','No Intervention']})
print(df_new)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid loops, because slow, so use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) or 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) for vectorized solution:

```
df['Intervention'] = np.where(df['Intervention'].isna(),'No Intervention','Yes Intervention')
```

Or:

```
df['Intervention'] = np.where(df['Intervention'].notna(),'Yes Intervention','No Intervention')
```

If `NaN` is string then test by `==` or [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df['Intervention']=np.where(df['Intervention'].eq('NaN'),'No Intervention','Yes Intervention')
```

But if need also test in list use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['Intervention'].isin(intervention_list)
m2 = df['Intervention'].isna()

#if not match m1 or m2 create default None
df['Intervention'] = np.select([m1, m2],
                              ['Yes Intervention','No Intervention'],
                              default=None)
```

---

```
#if not match m1 or m2 set original value column Intervention
df['Intervention'] = np.select([m1, m2],
                              ['Yes Intervention','No Intervention'],
                              default=df['Intervention'])
```

Comment: @Jake - Just realised also need test `intervention_list`, check edited answer.